# How to access the ISA Bus of a Windows PC?

Tags: windows, bus, isa-bus

I want to access my Motherboard's ISA Bus to read temperature sensor values and set cooling fan speeds.
I could not find any practically helpful information but the hint to use "GiveIO", a unviersial I/O driver which unfortunately is not compatible with windows 7.

If there is no avoiding of coding a driver, any useful information on how to get startet would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an open source hardware monitor at http://code.google.com/p/open-hardware-monitor that seems to do what you want. It uses the WinRing0 driver for hardware access.

Answer (score 1):

To directly access the hardware under Windows, one must write a device driver.